# Lubuntu desktop preferences

Tags: lubuntu, desktop-background

This morning, I turned on my computer and my custom wallpaper was replaced by the default Lubuntu (18.04) wallpaper, and all the desktop icons were reorganized, as if in an automated way, on the left side of the screen. These changes were easy to undo. But I am wondering what caused it. This has never happened before. Was this a consequence of a recent upgrade? Did anyone else experience it?

Comment: What version (18.04, etc) of Lubuntu do you use? Our Lubuntu systems were fine this morning. They are 18.04

Comment: Yes. I am using 18.04