# Lubuntu wallpaper and icon glitch

Tags: lubuntu, icons, desktop-background, preferences

I have been happily using Lubuntu 18.04 since the release was issued. Then 12 days ago, suddenly, for no reason I can understand, two glitches appeared in combination. Upon every shutdown and restart, the wallpaper reverts to `lubuntu-default-wallpaper.png` no matter how I customize it. Similarly, no matter how I organize my desktop icons, upon restart they all appear in a perfect grid in the upper left corner, ruining my own categories for my files. This is not how I want my system to function. Thinking that these glitches might be tied to an upgrade, I looked to see if anyone else reported it, but I could find no one 12 days ago, or since. Subsequent upgrades have not caused the problem to go away. I would appreciate any advice in trying to diagnose these glitches and fix them.

Comment: This appears to be essentially a duplicate of your [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108869/lubuntu-desktop-preferences)

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday, as I was unable to figure out why these glitches were happening, I decided to re-install LXDE to fix. I consolidated all of my files into one directory on the Desktop, to back everything up in one go, but I was interrupted, and I had to shut down before making a backup. Later, when I turned my computer on again, I found that both glitches had ceased. I turned the computer on and off several times. Still no return of those problems. My personalized wallpaper remained in tact, again, as did my desktop icon arrangement. I don't know if there is a causal connection or if it was coincidence. But the issue appeared to resolve following that action.